# Console font - how to show accents?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, console, locale

Arch linux on VirtualBox.

My problem is the console (not X) does not show accents like "á ã ç". The problem is showing, not typing. I have a text file with these accents and when I use "cat" the don't show correctly.

I *was* able to make it work with "setfont cp850-8x16", however, I do want to use Terminus (or some other font) and in any case, I want to understand why other fonts that should be capable of showing these characters (supposedly, Lat2-Terminus16 should handle them, but does not work) don't do that.

I already spent some hours on research and testing, and tried a bunch of setfont/loadunimap, and none helped except the one mentioned above. My guess is I have to do something about UNICODE before using the other fonts, but I do not know what.

It's surprising the low amount of resources on how to make stuff like this work.

The end result is that I should be able to type accents (pt_BR) with a beautiful font on the Console (text-mode).

Comment: Well done for finding it. Rather than updating your solution, please post it as an answer and accept it so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: I'll have to wait 6 hours for that.

Answer (score 3):

Oh well, the miracles of explaining a question does to one's own thinking.
I looked at it from the start again and went back to the wiki help article, and the solution is:

1. edit `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment the line about `en_US.UTF-8`
2. edit `/etc/locale.conf` and add/edit `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
3. reboot

Lessons learned: follow the tutorial/help, or at least understand it, before changing the steps for yourself.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale